# Skype won't work in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: upgrade, skype

I keep getting message telling me to upgrade to latest version of Skype to get video and pics. Which I have done, Beta 5, but I still get message to upgrade to latest version. I get audio but no video.
What can I do to correct?
Thanks

Comment: Apparently the only one that currently works is the one from the site.

Comment: I downloaded Deb from site